# Oil in radiator? 1991 Ford Telstar

Tags: engine, ford

The radiator water is a browny color and very viscous. Oil levels have dropped beneath minimum on dip stick after adding 1.5 liters of oil.

Comment: Are you asking what the problem is here? I don't really see a question.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds so much like a classic head gasket failure that it nearly couldn't sound like anything else except vandalism. Since I'm not quite clinically paranoid, I'm gonna' go with the head gasket thing.

Comment: Correct answer on both counts, though head gasket is my bet. Lol +1

Answer (score 1):

If differant antifreezes are mixed together, say blue and red, you will end up with a gooey brown fluid. The loss of oil sounds a puzzle. You are saying that you added 1.5 litres and then the oil level dropped, when it should have raised. Let your favourite mechanic have a look at the vehicle just to ascertain the problem.

Comment: Didn't know about the red and blue make brown (goo). +1